# Why would Cedric become a Death Eater?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters, the-cursed-child

Cedric was a good, and modest lad. Why would he join the death eaters?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [script](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child), his fall from grace stemmed from Scorpius and Albus mucking around with his timeline.

> **DELPHI:** *Voldemort ruled? He was alive?*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *He ruled everything. It was terrible.*
>
> **DELPHI:** *Because of what we did?*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** ***Humiliating Cedric turned him into a very angry young man, and then he became a Death Eater** and — and — it all went wrong. Really wrong.*

---

As to ***why*** Cedric would turn evil, it's fairly noticeable that although he's superficially friendly and charming, he's also quite ambitious and driven. He (just about) passes one test of character by giving Harry a hint about the egg but then systematically fails the second by not rescuing the other hostages in the lake task.

In short, we really don't know enough about his character to know whether him turning evil is *out-of-character*.

Comment: Regarding the lake task, I don't think that says anything about his character one way or the other. Wasn't the point that you weren't expected to rescue the other hostages? I never got the impression that was the secret goal of the task. More of a "let's pretend for now that your hostage is the only hostage. Don't worry, they aren't in any real danger, so you can ignore the others."

Comment: @Alarion - Well, Harry got extra points for moral virtue in that task. Cedric and Krum didn't.